# How often were names ending in -um used in real life?

Tags: classical-latin, names

There seem to be a number of examples of personal names ending in *-um* in the works of Plautus (apparently, they also show up in Terence<sup>1</sup>). In a discussion on Wiktionary, I found an interesting [comment by the editor Smurrayinchester](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Talk:Pyrgopolynices#Deletion_discussion) which makes the point that at least some of the names found in Plautus' plays "aren't Latin names any more than Nanki-Poo or Obi-Wan Kenobi are English names", and cites a text that says

> there are good reasons to believe that Plautus invented many of his characters' names, especially those with humorous Greek etymologies. [...] The *-ium* at the end of courtesans' names is derived from an affectionate Greek diminutive; *Philocomasium* means "Love a Party" and *Acroleutium* "The Absolute End". We cannot tell how many members of Plautus' Roman audience knew enough Greek to appreciate these etymologies.

("[Introduction to Miles Gloriosus](https://books.google.de/books?id=Aj-5l63TFxwC&pg=PA13)", by Peter L. Smith, in *Plautus: Three Comedies,* (1991), p. 13)

How much evidence do we have for names ending in *(i)um* being used in Latin outside of fictional contexts? Naively, I would assume that if Plautus used this ending extensively in his plays, he would expect his audiences to at least be familiar with personal names ending in *-(i)um*, even if they didn't know enough Greek to identify all of the meaningful elements of the names.

I found a brief mention of such names in a section of "[Some Roman Slave-names](https://theologicalstudies.org.uk/pdf/ffb/slave-names_bruce.pdf)" by F. F. Bruce:

> Greek diminutives in *-ιον,* mainly names of women [...]
> appear in Latin with the ending *-ium* as well [as the ending *-io*]. Thus *Φιλημάτιον* takes in Latin the forms Philematium and (as here) Philematio.

Bruce lists many inscriptional examples of names ending in *-io;* some examples of names written with the ending *-ion;* but as far as I can see no examples of inscriptions that spell a name with *-ium.* (There are some other sources for names ending in *-io* and *-ion.*)

#### Citations

1. Henry John Roby, *[Grammar of the Latin Language from Plautus to Suetonius, Part 1](https://books.google.com/books?id=hIlfAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA106),* p. 106